# 'bower' is not recognized, want to have Jenkins install grunt, bower

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, jenkins

I am getting the issue 'bower' is not recognized while running my Jenkins project as I have seen many other people get. However, I know I can get it to work by including the hardcoded path

```
C:\Users\clang\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

in my path environment variable. This is not the way I want to do it though.

My goal is to have this Jenkins configuration be able to download, install, and run these commands locally and be able to do so without hardcoding a path as I want it to run on other computers that would have different users hence different paths. This is my current batch script that I am running.

```
set PATH=%PATH%; %WORKSPACE%\.bin;
call npm install
call npm install bower
call npm install grunt-cli
call bower install
call grunt build
```

when bower and grunt are installed by this, the bower.cmd and grunt.cmd are located in this directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ClearWork\.bin
```

The command I am running at the top does in fact evaluate to and include the directory where these command files are located but for some reason I am still getting the error saying that bower and grunt are not recognized.

Just to make sure it wasn't an issue with the Jenkins %Workspace% environment variable I even hard coded the location which gave the same result.

Comment: Which directory location do you run your batch script from? Do you double-click it?

Comment: When Jenkins runs the batch script it is from

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ClearWork

Comment: I was wrong to say that I verified I could use it because if I go to both places in the command line and try bower install I get two different errors. For the one in C:\Users\clang\AppData\Roaming\npm I get the error "No bower.json" when I run bower install whereas I get the error "Name must be lowercase..." when I run bower install on the one at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ClearWork\.bin

Comment: but the build does work if I include the hardcoded C:\Users\clang\AppData\Roaming\npm in my path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
call node_modules/.bin/bower install
call node_modules/.bin/grunt build
```

**Option 2**

Add these as scripts to the package.json:

(inside package.json)

```
  "scripts": {
    "bower:install": "bower install",
    "grunt:build": "grunt build"
  }
```

Now you should be able to call:

```
call npm run bower:install
call npm run grunt:build
```

Because npm automatically adds node_modules/.bin to the path

Comment: oh man, thanks for the answer. I went with option 1. I don't know how I thought about using the path variable and not calling it with the relative path instead. I guess I figured I needed to use an absolute path since that's what I had seen in all the examples. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem :-).  Glad I could help.